# Simple Quadratic and Linear Equation Calculator

Tags: python, logic

I'm having difficulties with a simple linear and quadratic equation calculator. The quadratic works, but the linear doesn't. It gives me the answer in float, but for some reason it's always some number and then 0. For example: if I want to solve **2x + 13 = 0**, the answer will be **-7.0**, though it should be **-6.5**. I guess it rounds it up (ceiling) for some reason. I'm pretty sure I have some syntax error somewhere, but I can't find it.
Any suggestions for how to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help.

```
import math

a,b,c = input("Enter the coefficients of a, b and c separated by commas: ")

d = b**2-4*a*c # discriminant

if a == 0:
    x = -c/b # liner equation
    x = float(x)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)
    print "This linear equation has one solution:", x

elif d < 0:
    print "This quadratic equation has no real solution"

elif d == 0:
    x = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print "This quadratic equation has one solutions:", x

else:
    x1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print "This quadratic equation has two solutions:", x1, "and", x2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = -c/b` - If c and b are both integers then the result will be rounded to an integer as well.

Do something like `x = -c/float(b)`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I can see my mistake now: I was trying to convert it too late. Thank you for your quick response Tomer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `a`, `b` and `c` to floats right after the user input.

Another way is to use [Python 3.x division](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Operators#Division_and_Type_Conversion), which will work as you expect, with

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: BTW, do you know how to run the code again in the Python Shell without going back to the text editor and pressing "run module" on Windows 7? It's really annoying.

Comment: Wrap it up in a function (i.e. put `def calculate():` or similar after `import math` and indent the rest of your code) and call that function from the shell